# plotting hypergeometric functions

Tags: plotting, special-functions

Does anyone know why a plot of a hypergeometric function turns out differently in *Mathematica* than in *Maple*?

The function I'm plotting between x=-30 and +30 is:

```
Re[Exp[-2 I p x]*(Conjugate[A]*Cosh[q - x]^(v + 1)*
Hypergeometric2F1[0.5 (v + 1 - I), 0.5 (v + 1 + I), 
 1/2, -Sinh[q - x]^2] + 
 Conjugate[B]*Cosh[q - x]^(v + 1)*Sinh[q - x]*
 Hypergeometric2F1[0.5 (v + 1 - I) + 0.5, 0.5 (v + 1 + I) + 0.5, 
   3/2, -Sinh[q - x]^2])*(A*Cosh[q + x]^(v + 1)*
  Hypergeometric2F1[0.5 (v + 1 + I), 0.5 (v + 1 - I), 
   1/2, -Sinh[q + x]^2] + 
 B*Cosh[q + x]^(v + 1)*Sinh[q + x]*
  Hypergeometric2F1[0.5 (v + 1 + I) + 0.5, 0.5 (v + 1 - I) + 0.5, 
   3/2, -Sinh[q + x]^2])]
```

where `q=p=3`, `v=1`, `A=0.5+0.5I` and `B=-1+I`.

I've attached both plots from *Maple* (first image) and *Mathematica* (second image)

[image: Maple plot]

[image: Mathematica [;pt]

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be a numerical issue.  The first step in cases like this is to re-write your problem in terms of [exact rather than approximate numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html).  This basically boils down to replacing all instances of 0.5 with 1/2:

```
f[x_] := Re[Exp[-2 I p x]*(Conjugate[A] Cosh[q - x]^(v + 1) Hypergeometric2F1[
    1/2 (v + 1 - I), 1/2 (v + 1 + I), 1/2, -Sinh[q - x]^2] + 
  Conjugate[B]*
   Cosh[q - x]^(v + 1) Sinh[q - x] Hypergeometric2F1[
    1/2 (v + 1 - I) + 1/2, 1/2 (v + 1 + I) + 1/2, 
    3/2, -Sinh[q - x]^2])*(A*Cosh[q + x]^(v + 1)*
   Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (v + 1 + I), 1/2 (v + 1 - I), 
    1/2, -Sinh[q + x]^2] + 
  B*Cosh[q + x]^(v + 1) Sinh[q + x] Hypergeometric2F1[
    1/2 (v + 1 + I) + 1/2, 1/2 (v + 1 - I) + 1/2, 
    3/2, -Sinh[q + x]^2])];

p = 3; q = 3; v = 1; A = 1/2 + 1/2*I; B = -1 + I;
```

We can see right away that there are some numerical issues:

```
In[7]:= N[f[21], 50]
```

(* 0.73319032007329183856302280309650876469026021907524 *)

```
N[f[21]]
```

(* Indeterminate *)

Therefore, you will likely have to increase the WorkingPrecision of Plot to a larger value.  This appears to produce the same result that you got from Maple:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -30, 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

[image]